# Getting each field following regular pattern with awk

Tags: awk, pattern-matching

Having an input text file as below:

```
1234, aaa = 34 </T><AT/>X_CONST = 34 </T><AT/>AAA_Z = 3 </T><AT/>Y_CONST = 34 </T><AT/>FOUND_ME_1 = 5 </T><AT/>BBB_X = 3 </T><AT/>CCC_X = 8 </T><AT/>FOUND_ME_2 = 8 </T><AT/>FOUND_ME_3 = 8 </T><AT/>RRR_Z = 3 </T><AT/>T_CONST = 37 </T><AT/>FOUND_ME_4 = 10 </T><AT/>X_CONST = 34
7844, aaa = 33 </T><AT/>X_CONST = 21 </T><AT/>AAA_Z = 3 </T><AT/>R_CONST = 34 </T><AT/>FOUND_ME_1 = 50 </T><AT/>BBB_X = 3 </T><AT/>CCC_X = 8 </T><AT/>FOUND_ME_2 = 81 </T><AT/>FOUND_ME_3 = 8 </T><AT/>RRR_Z = 3 </T><AT/>T_CONST = 37 </T><AT/>X_CONST = 55
8888, aaa = 31 </T><AT/>X_CONST = 21 </T><AT/>AAA_Z = 3 </T><AT/>R_CONST = 34 </T><AT/>FOUND_ME_1 = 54 </T><AT/>BBB_Z = 3 </T><AT/>CCC_X = 8 </T><AT/>FOUND_ME_2 = 81 </T><AT/>FOUND_ME_3 = 8 </T><AT/>RRR_Z = 3 </T><AT/>T_CONST = 37 </T><AT/>FOUND_ME_4 = 11 </T><AT/>X_CONST = 55 </T><AT/>FOUND_ME_5 = 8 </T><AT/>TTT_X = 8 </T><AT/>FOUND_ME_6 = 20
```

I need to extract all the values related to the field FOUND_ME_[0-9] , possibly with awk. I know that converting each field to separate lines it would be easier but I'm finding a solution working with the file as it is.

My goal is to have an output like the following (values separated by commas)

```
5, 8, 8, 10
50, 81, 8
54, 81, 8, 11, 8, 20
```

I'm trying the following but no luck:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i==".*FOUND_ME_[0-9]"){print $($i+2)} } }'
```

I have also problems with this special regular pattern FOUND_ME_[0-9]

Answer (score 1):

This awk script gets you the output you want (although I'm guessing that file might have started out as XML once upon a time...):

```
$ cat script.awk
BEGIN { FS = "[[:space:]=]+" }
{
    s = ""
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) 
        if($i ~ /FOUND_ME_[0-9]/)
            s = s sprintf("%s, ", $(++i)) 
    print substr(s, 1, length(s) - 2)
}
$ awk -f script.awk file
5, 8, 8, 10
50, 81, 8
54, 81, 8, 11, 8, 20
```

It builds a string `s` from the field after each one matching the pattern. `sprintf("%s, ", $(++i))` returns the value of the next field followed by a comma and a space. `$(++i)` increments the field number `i` and then returns the value of the field. In awk, strings are concatenated, so the string returned by `sprintf` is added to the existing value of `s`.

I set the field separator `FS` to one or more space or `=` characters, so the field you're interested is the one after the one matching the pattern. Note that I'm using `~` to match a regex pattern - you cannot use `==` as you were doing as this performs a string comparison.

The `substr` strips the last `,` from the the string before it is printed.

A much shorter option, inspired by [Kent's use of `FPAT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29791930/2088135) on GNU awk (note that this requires a version >=4.0) :

```
$ awk -v FPAT="FOUND_ME_[0-9] *= *[0-9]+" -v OFS=", " '{$1=$1;gsub(/FOUND_ME_[0-9] *= */,"")}1' file
5, 8, 8, 10
50, 81, 8
54, 81, 8, 11, 8, 20
```

`$1=$1` causes awk to "touch" each record, removing the parts which aren't matched by `FPAT`. `gsub` performs a global substitution, removing the part we aren't interested in. `1` at the end is always true, so the default action `{print}` is performed. Setting the `OFS` variable causes each field in the output to be comma-separated as desired.

Comment: Why are you using sprintf ?

Comment: @JID so that I can remove the last couple of characters from `s` - couldn't think of a nicer way at the time...anyway, I've just posted a much shorter option.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the answer. It works. Could you tell me in detail what the espression " s = s sprintf("%s, ", $(++i)); " does?

Comment: @John I've added to my explanation, does that make sense?

Comment: why s = s sprintf ... and not s = sprintf... What does the "s" after the "=" represents?

Comment: The version in my code concatenates the current value of `s` with the output of `sprintf`, whereas without the `s` on the other side of the assignment, `s` would lose its current value every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

**gawk** has `FPAT`, which we could use for this problem:

```
awk -v FPAT="FOUND_ME_[0-9] *= *[0-9]+" '
  {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sub("FOUND_ME_[0-9] *= *","",$i);
    printf "%s%s",$i,(NF==i?"\n":", ")}}' file
```

output:

```
5, 8, 8, 10
50, 81, 8
54, 81, 8, 11, 8, 20
```